# XQuery and XPath Assertions in SOAP UI Project do not run from JUnit

Tags: java, soap, junit, xquery, soapui

The testcases run fine in SOAP UI Itself. Other `contains` assertions also run fine. However XPath And XQuery Assertions Fail with this exception

"RuntimeException:No query engine found"

I assume I need to add a dependency, but I don't know which one

```
  SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner(); 
  runner.setProjectFile( "src/test/java/soapui.xml" );
  runner.run();
```

I am referring to this link https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html

Dependencies for soapui:

```
<groupId>eviware</groupId>
  <artifactId>soapui-xmlbeans</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
  <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please show how you are running the tests?

Comment: added the sample code, it is from this link https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html

Comment: Was the assertion working when it is run from soapui tool?

Comment: Yes, only the Xquery/Xpath assertions dont work from java, contains assertions work

Comment: Can you show your classpath used in the java project? Running from eclipse?

Comment: yes i am using eclipse, and i am not sure what you mean by the classpath. I have included all dependencies in maven... .is there any specific dependency for Xquery/Xpath Engine

Comment: No voice in maven. By the way, how does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: I am not at liberty to share that, in have edited the question to include relevant dependencies